# HTTP-протокол для С++

Tags: c++, http

Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос покажется немного некоренным, но вопрос такой:

Вот есть к примеру у меня готовый код, который работает на портах завершения WIndows, то есть я могу отправить буфер с любыми данными на сервер и принять в буфер любые данные с сервера.

Предположим общение с сервером нужно вести по наиболее распространённому протоколу http/http2 1.1, 2.0.
Реализовать эти протоколы самому с нуля займет просто мне кажется огромное время, и в итоге, если даже и получится реализовать, к моменту реализации - это уже будет не нужно ни мне ни кому то другому.

И вот вопрос: есть ли готовые хорошие библиотеки с++, которые могли бы за меня так сказать общаться по http/https, НО отправку и прием запросов и сообщений я бы делал "своими силами" ?

То есть к примеру:

-мне нужно отправить условно get запрос на сервер, я вызываю соответствующий условный метод get из библиотеки, а библиотека формирует корректный get запрос, к примеру в случае с http 2.0 дополнительно сжимает http-заголовки и возвращает мне готовый буфер c данным корректным запросом, и я уже этот буфер отправляю "своими" силами на сервер.

-и тоже самое, но уже с приемом сообщения от сервера: я принимаю сообщение с севера и по мере заполнения буфера - предоставляю этот буфер методам библиотеки, что бы она сама распознала, что пришло с сервера, если к примеру данные сжаты gzip, то разжала их и в итоге предоставила, готовый в отдельный буффер.

В общем вот как то так ? Такое вообще возможно ?

Comment: обычно это делается немного по-другому: в большинстве библиотек есть способ установить callback, который будет вызываться вместо отправки даннных во внутренний сокет... приложение в свою очередь может сделать с этими данными что захочет, например, записать на флешки и отправить голубями вместо классических реализаций ip... например для банального curl'а, см. [external socket example](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=libcurl+use+external+socket)

Comment: @ Fat-Zer, это я понимаю. Но, я, как раз хотел за место этого "callback" использовать свою реализацию отправки и приема, а вот обработку HTTP/HTTPS - использовать именно библиотечную.

Comment: ну дык, в обратный вызов ты и передаёшь свою реализацию отправки/приёма...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, с первого раза не понял. Спасибо. Буду дальше гуглить.

Comment: Как насчёт boost beast - https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html ?

Comment: @VladimirS, я как раз его смотрю, но, как получить из него то, что мне надо пока не понял. То есть, как boost.beast`у подсунуть именно мою реализацию отправки и приемки.

Comment: @VladimirS, boost.beast - как написано в самой документации реализует только часть http 1.1 протокола.

Comment: @VladimirS, и boost beast использует boost.asio - то есть он никаким образом не позволяет сделать то, о чем я спросил.

Comment: @Fat-Zer , да, но, как я понял - эти call-бэки все равно работают с функциями библиотеки, в вашем примере Curl. Я ни как не могу заменить их на собственную реализацию приема/отправки.

Comment: @Optimus1, на счёт libcurl я похоже ошибся: [оно так не умеет](https://curl.se/mail/lib-2018-07/0050.html)... бегло просматривал пример и меня ввела в заблуждение `write_data()` — подумал, что это запись в сокет, а не просто вывод... с beast'ом успех тоже не снискал?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, beast работает только с boost.asio и там тоже свои функции подставлять нет возможности. Вероятнее всего такой библиотеки, которая бы такое умела нет в принципе - потому что это или не возможно или очень сложно по всей видимости реализовать.

Comment: @Optimus1, вот [здесь](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/2055) говорят что это можно сделать… если кратко, то на основе [примера](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/async/http_client_async.cpp) надо подсунуть свою реализацию `stream_` вместо `beast::tcp_stream`… но найти какой-либо конкретный пример или сварганить по-быстрому на коленке у меня не получилось…